# Find out the speed of the User in android Using GPS

Tags: android, location

I tried to find out the speed of User, while user is moving with device. Here, I followed one link with sample code. i.e: [Here](http://code.google.com/p/krvarma-android-samples/source/browse/#svn/trunk/SpeedDemo) SpeedDemo.

The problem is, by using `location.getSpeed()` method, we are finding the speed. So, for that I changed the location values in device, but every time the value of the `location.getspeed()` return '0' only. Why it happen, even changing the location itself.

Can any one known about this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to track location Updates, and when the method `onLocationChanged(Location location)` triggers, you can call `location.getSpeed();` it will give you correct speed, if your phone is actually moving.

But if you are testing it on Simulator, and sending location by emulator controller, it will always return 0.

**`Updated with Example`**

```
public class LocationService implements LocationListener {

    LocationService locationService;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    Location lastLocation;
    private final String TAG = "LocationService" ;

    private final String MOCK_LOCAION_PROVIDER = "FAKE_PROVIDER";

    LocationService(Context ctx) {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        String mocLocationProvider = MOCK_LOCAION_PROVIDER;


        if (locationManager.getProvider(mocLocationProvider) != null) {
            locationManager.removeTestProvider(mocLocationProvider);
        }
        locationManager.addTestProvider(mocLocationProvider, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, 0, 5);

        locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(mocLocationProvider, true);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(mocLocationProvider, 0, 0,
        this);


        try {

            List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
            InputStream is = ctx.getAssets().open("data.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                data.add(line);
            }
            // Log.e(TAG, data.size() + " lines");

            new MockLocationProvider(locationManager, mocLocationProvider, data).start();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    class MockLocationProvider extends Thread {

        private List<String> data;
        private LocationManager locationManager;
        private String mocLocationProvider;
        private String LOG_TAG = "MockLocationProvider";

        public MockLocationProvider(LocationManager locationManager, String mocLocationProvider, List<String> data) throws IOException {

            this.locationManager = locationManager;
            this.mocLocationProvider = mocLocationProvider;
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            for (String str : data) {

                try {

                    Thread.sleep(5000);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Set one position
                String[] parts = str.split(",");
                Double latitude = Double.valueOf(parts[0]);
                Double longitude = Double.valueOf(parts[1]);
                float speed = Float.valueOf(parts[2]);
                Location location = new Location(mocLocationProvider);
                location.setLatitude(latitude);
                location.setLongitude(longitude);
                location.setSpeed(speed);
                // location.setAltitude(altitude);

                // Log.d(LOG_TAG, location.toString());

                // set the time in the location. If the time on this location
                // matches the time on the one in the previous set call, it will
                // be
                // ignored
                location.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());

                locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(mocLocationProvider, location);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged");

        // Get Location Speed Here
        Log.d(TAG, "Speed " +location.getSpeed());



    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled : "+provider);
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled : "+provider);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged : "+status);
    }
}
```

The Above code is actually a location service class, when you make an instance of this class, it register a fake Location Service(other than GPS, and Network) provider, and input some fake location parameters by a given file.

Below is the data.txt file which has `latitude,longitude,speed` the above class read this data.txt file and input fake lat,lon, and speed in the location, as well as trigger time to change location is also implemented by `Thread.sleep()` call.

**Data.txt file**

```
24.856449265609735,67.04308920288086,1.64
24.856749265609735,67.04408920288086,7.64
24.856949265609735,67.04508920288086,11.64
24.857649265609735,67.04716920288086,13.64
24.857949265609735,67.04736920288086,12.64
24.857949265609735,67.04742520288086,8.64
24.857949265609735,67.04747020288086,4.64
24.856749265609735,67.04408920288086,6.11
24.856949265609735,67.04508920288086,2.12
24.857249265609735,67.04608920288086,1.1
24.856949265609735,67.04508920288086,2.13
24.857249265609735,67.04608920288086,0.6
24.856949265609735,67.04508920288086,1.19
24.857249265609735,67.04608920288086,1.6
24.856949265609735,67.04508920288086,2.12
24.857249265609735,67.04608920288086,1.15
24.857849265609735,67.04729920288086,17.64
24.857949265609735,67.04736920288086,12.64
24.857949265609735,67.04739920288086,16.64
24.857949265609735,67.04742520288086,8.64
24.857949265609735,67.04747020288086,4.64
24.856749265609735,67.04408920288086,6.11
24.856949265609735,67.04508920288086,2.12
24.857249265609735,67.04608920288086,1.1
24.856949265609735,67.04508920288086,2.13
24.857249265609735,67.04608920288086,0.6
24.856949265609735,67.04508920288086,1.19
24.857249265609735,67.04608920288086,1.6
24.856949265609735,67.04508920288086,2.12
24.857249265609735,67.04608920288086,1.15
24.857849265609735,67.04729920288086,17.64
24.857949265609735,67.04736920288086,12.64
24.857949265609735,67.04739920288086,16.64
24.857949265609735,67.04742520288086,8.64
24.857949265609735,67.04747020288086,4.64
24.856749265609735,67.04408920288086,6.11
24.856949265609735,67.04508920288086,2.12
24.857249265609735,67.04608920288086,1.1
24.857849265609735,67.04729920288086,17.64
24.857949265609735,67.04736920288086,12.64
24.857949265609735,67.04739920288086,16.64
24.857949265609735,67.04742520288086,8.64
24.857949265609735,67.04747020288086,4.64
24.856749265609735,67.04408920288086,6.11
24.856949265609735,67.04508920288086,2.12
24.857249265609735,67.04608920288086,1.15
24.856949265609735,67.04508920288086,2.13
24.857249265609735,67.04608920288086,0.6
24.856949265609735,67.04508920288086,1.19
24.857249265609735,67.04608920288086,1.6
24.856949265609735,67.04508920288086,2.12
24.857249265609735,67.04608920288086,1.15
24.856949265609735,67.04508920288086,2.13
24.857249265609735,67.04608920288086,0.6
24.856949265609735,67.04508920288086,1.19
24.857249265609735,67.04608920288086,1.6
24.856949265609735,67.04508920288086,2.12
24.857249265609735,67.04608920288086,1.15
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, Moving with device was not possible, because I'm working in LAN. Out of the area, GPS was not working for me. So, I changed my device locations itself by providing fake values. Still value '0'. Is there any way to find the out put by changing locations.Changed location values are printed correctly, but out put was same.

Comment: Are you using mocklocation to input fake value, if yes, then you should also set the location.setSpeed(float meters) .

Comment: I have just downloaded fakeGPS app from market, and changing each and every time my location values and checking my application for out put. Can u please explain me about location.setSpeed(float meters). Where can i use this exactly..??

Comment: It's working fine with my previous snippet. The thing behind this is, previously i was just moved little for changing locations. So, it wont work. Now, I was moved with my device by vehicle. By this only, the location values are changed. Thanks once again Adeel.

Answer (score 1):

I think getSpeed() will work only if the particular location have speed component available with GPS. Otherwise it will returned 0.0 all the time.

For that you can check that using condition location.hasSpeed() method. If true then do your stuff else think another way.

Comment: what you are saying is that location.hasSpeed() method is not available for all locations (with certain lat,lng). And if location.hasSpeed() is not available then location.getSpeed() method will return 0.0?

Comment: Yes, if your device GPS have speed component then only it will return proper value else it will return 0.0 all the time. So please check with hasSpeed() method first and then go ahead. @QadirHussain

Answer (score -1):

First we need to check whether the Gps Enabled or not using location manager.

```
isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Then , you need to implement GpsStatus.Listener to get the Gps updates. It will return the Gps location updates.

```
GPSManager.locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
                            if (GPSManager.gpsCallback != null) {
                                    GPSManager.gpsCallback.onGPSUpdate(location);
                            }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(final String provider) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderEnabled(final String provider) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(final String provider, final int status, final Bundle extras) {
                    }
            };
```

From that location you can able to get the current speed.

```
speed = location.getSpeed();
```

Refer to my website here for further details : http://velmm.com/get-current-user-speed-using-gps-android/