# Why does location.getSpeed() always return 0

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3, locationmanager, android-gps

I need to get my speed from myLocation , it always returns 0 ... I need help

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.e("location",String.valueOf(location.getSpeed()));
}
```

Comment: Log.e("speed",String.valueOf(location.getSpeed()));

Comment: How fast are moving when testing this? And if you are using network based location, then it's not accurate enough for calculating the speed. GPS based location is needed.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen I am using only the GPS mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply [`getSpeed()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getSpeed()) method only returns the speed if it is available,

> If this location does not have a speed then 0.0 is returned.

If you are sure you have proper speed to be shown and has to be returned something surely then consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11843861/5067493) codes, And try making your's same as that one.