# Android Location getSpeed always returns 0.0 when on Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-location

I have a class which implements the LocationListener and in my class I have implemented the onLocationChanged method.

The location.getLongitude() returns a valid value however the location.getSpeed() always returns 0.0

I am using Android's emulator and am uploading a gpx file from [Open Street Map](http://www.openstreetmap.org/user/wope1/traces/2174417) through the Load GPX/KML file option.

Can you please help me understand why it is always turning up as 0.0?

Answer (score 1):

You should be always aware that [`getSpeed()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getSpeed()) method returns the speed **if it is available.**

> If this location does not have a speed then 0.0 is returned.

Consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11843861/5067493) example, Try to make your codes like this, If you got any trouble further.

Comment: How is the value set in the location? Is this something I need to define in the file?

Comment: Why should I use a mock service? shouldn't the GPS GPX file replace the need for the mock service?

Comment: Then why do you have to use mock service ?

Comment: I don't understand why I should be implementing a mock service if I am using the GPX files through the emulator.

Comment: I also didn't understand why you are talking about mock service in the case of getSpeed() method.